Переключение между окнами в qt c++
Делаю приложение на qt, в котором предполагается 8-12 окон (не диалоговые, все в одном как в инсталяторе).
Окна взаимосвязаны друг с другом, как можно организовать подобную логику? Знаю, что есть способ через QStackedWidget, но насколько это оптимально при таком количестве окон?
В том же реакте для подобного рода вещей есть стейт менеджер (Redux, MobX и тд).

Оптимально, не сомневайтесь
